# Почему не работает код?Html/JS

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JS в Sublime Text.
Пытаюсь создать что-то типо онлайн калькулятора по видеоуроку, но он не работает и выбивает ошибку: [1113/194018.329:ERROR:crash_report_database_win.cc(428)] unexpected header

код:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" defer>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Number1: <input type="text" id="n1"></p>
    <p>Number2: <input type="text" id="n2"></p>
    <button onclick="plus()">Add</button>
    <button onclick="minus()">Subtract</button>
    <hr>
    <p id="out">Result</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function plus() {
var num1, num2, result;
num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
num1 = parseInt(num1);
num2 = parseInt(num2);
result = num1 + num2;
result = document.getElementById('out').innerHTML;

}

function minus() {
var num1, num2, result;
num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
num1 = parseInt(num1);
num2 = parseInt(num2);
result = num1 + num2;
result = document.getElementById('out').innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: ошибка в вопросе похоже к коду не имеет отношения

Comment: Скрипты всегда подключайте **перед** закрывающим тэгом `</body>`

Answer (score 2):

```
//result = document.getElementById('out').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = result;

function minus() {
  ...
  result = num1 - num2;
  ...
}
```